# How to have more than one include on the same page in PHP

Tags: php, include

The title says it all, I've been trying to get this to work but it isn't working for me. It is just displaying the first include.

```
<?php include 'config.php';  include 'https://theurl/that_the_header_is_on/header.php';  include '$header_url';  ?>
```

EDIT: The error is here:

> [11-Dec-2016 03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning: include(): http://
>   wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
>   in /home/myurlf/public_html/SimplePages/index.php on line 4
>   [11-Dec-2016 03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:
>   include(myurl.fluctis.com/SimplePages/Default/1.0/header.php‌​):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /home/myurlf/public_html/SimplePages/index.php on line 4 [11-Dec-2016
>   03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening

Comment: It is unclear what you actually try to do. Certainly you can include more than a single file using separate `include` statements divided by a semi colon. Your code has unbalanced quote chars and seems to miss some semi colon...

Comment: A general hint: when programming php script in a http server environment you _have to_ monitor hte http servers error log file. Otherwise this is a blind flight, you have to _guess_ what is going on. Never a good idea.

Comment: Can you fix my code? I have no idea what I did wrong, I have a variable in config.php called header_url I want to be able to get that variable and use it in the include variable, but it is not allowing more than one include.

Comment: I mentioned in my first comment that it is unclear what you actually try to do. Then how do you expect us to "fix" your code? What do you mean by "include variable"? What do you mean by "not allowing"? And as said: certainly multiple `include` statements are possible, _if you use valid syntax_, as explained in my first comment.

Comment: The error is here: [11-Dec-2016 03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /home/myurlf/public_html/SimplePages/index.php on line 4
[11-Dec-2016 03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  include(http://myurl.fluctis.com/SimplePages/Default/1.0/header.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/myurlf/public_html/SimplePages/index.php on line 4
[11-Dec-2016 03:26:13 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening

Comment: Thanks, but _please_ do not add further details in comments. Add them to the question. There is an `edit` link below it for that. _Use it_.

Comment: But anyway: your error message is crystal clear, isn't it? It does allow to use URLs with `include` in your current configuration.

Comment: How would I allow that arkascha?

Comment: Did you even bother to _read_ the error message? It tells you what you ask! "http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0". So obviously you have to change that!

Comment: I did read it, how would I change it? I'm using cPanel.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you, it is your system. But I expect such things to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

This should make code run. But...

```
  <?php 
  include('config.php');        
  include('https://theurl/that_the_header_is_on/header.php');
  include($header_url);
?>
```

Are you trying to do this? .. your post is a little confusing

```
<?php 
  include('config.php');        
  $header_url = 'Includes/header.php';
  include($header_url);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to get the variable $header_url from the config.php then get the header in a include from the link given from $header_url

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is what I currently using.

```
/**
 * Load all the class under RTlib\RTphp
 *
 * @return boolean False if error
 */
function RTphpLoad() {

    $lib = array();
    $lib[] = '/src/RTmysqli.php';
    $lib[] = '/src/RTpassword.php';
    $lib[] = '/src/RTslugify.php';
    $lib[] = '/src/RTutil.php';

    try {
        foreach ($lib as $class) {
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . $class;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        trigger_error('RTphpLoad() Fail to load. ' . $ex->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

In another php file

```
require_once FILEROOT . 'RTlib/RTphp/load.php';

RTphpLoad();
```